# Asp.net Web API http response data size

Tags: json, performance, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponse

I have an asp.net web api with getting a list of data from database with **a very heavy sql query**(using store procedure) then serialize to json, **my data result could return sometime more than 100,000 rows of data and is beyond the max limitation of http JSON response which is 4MB**, I've been trying to use pagination to limit my result size but **it pulls down performance as everytime user click on next page will trigger a heavy sql command**, but if I don't use pagination, sometimes the result data size is more than 4MB, and my client side grid won't render properly. Since I don't have a way to check the JSON data size before sending back to client from web api. So my questions would be:

1. Is there any way to check data size in asp.net web api before sending back to client? For example, if it's more than 4MB then send a response saying "please modify your date range to have less data"? Would this be a good idea in application design?
2. Is there any way to save the entire data result in cache or
   somewhere with asp.net web api so that every time when user perform a
   pagination, it will not get result again from database but from the
   cache.
3. Is there any way to store the entire data result in cache or in a temp file on client side(using Angular 5) so that when user perform a pagination, it will not request another http call to web api.

I would be more than happy to listen any experience or suggestion from anyone! Thank you very much!

Comment: You should be updating your API to expose data based on pagination and filter the data from DB using the page data instead of pulling all the data from DB every time.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand quite well.. Instead of pulling from DB every time is exactly what I want, but where is the page data that is going to apply pagination and filter? Is that still from DB? If so, it's still a performance issue to me because my query runs similar time when have a where condition for filter or a fetch next for pagination..

Comment: You could use Framework for optimizing the query result between your Web API and the DB. I'm not sure if that would solve your whole problem, but I think it can help. Please, take a look at this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515644/7389293